# In what order to execute git commands to pull changes from staging, merge with feature, and push to remote?

Tags: git, github, staging

I have feature branch called `feature` and a staging branch called `staging.` How do I get the most recent updates to `staging` and merge it into `feature` before pushing `feature` to Github?

Comment: The order is exactly as you have written in the text: first merge, then push. Was there any particular problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Before, I pulled into staging and then did `git rebase staging` when on the `feature` branch. After resolving conflicts, somehow, someone else's commits where shown as my personal changes when I made a pull request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would ran something like:

```
git fetch --all       (update your git's knowledge of remote stuff)
git checkout feature  ('tags' your folder as code belonging to feature branch and downloading the code)
git pull origin staging  (downloads staging code and but keeps it as code belonging to feature branch)
git add .            (marks all code changes for commit)
git commit -m'my awesome code changes' ( commits)
git push origin feature  (Pushing all your changes to feature branch)
```

Well, after pull you most likely will need to solve all conflicts. But this is out of the scope :)

But before running any commands from a guy from internet...do a reserve copy :)

Comment: Thank you for answering! Where does this merge the staging code into my feature branch?

Comment: Well, you checkout 'feature' code. So your folder at this point have all it's code and it 'tagged' as 'feature's code. Than you do 'pull' , that will download all staging code,but will keep your folder 'tagged' as 'feature's code